# C# fluent assertions result of check as bool

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I am trying to use Fluent Assertions on C# outside of test frameworks. Is there any way I could cast an FA check to bool? For example I need to achieve something like:

```
bool result= a.Should().Be(0);
```

If passes then result = true;
if fails, result = false.

Is there any way of casting or extracting a `bool` result from the assertion?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the test framework in your code as opposed to just writing `bool result = a == 0;`?

Comment: Hi greenjaed. It is sort of exercise, where I want to display on concole tests info. As I have tests using XUnit framework, where I used FluertAssertions, it is the easiest way to copy    all checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fluent Assertions is designed to throw exceptions that testing frameworks catch, not to return values.

About the best you can do is to create a method that accepts an action, and that catches the exception when the action throws. In the `catch` you'd return `false`.

```
public bool Evaluate(Action a)
{
    try
    {
        a();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
bool result = Evaluate(() => a.Should().Be(0));
```

This will have terrible performance in the negative case; throwing exceptions is not cheap. You might get frowns from others because, generally, [exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control).

That said, this does what you want.

Comment: Note that this would return false when the delegate throws an exception itself, rather than rethrowing it.

Comment: Yes, that is what the OP wanted -- a `false` value when the assertion failed.

Comment: Thank you, This answers my question. I just thought they may be built in mechanism I do not know in Fluent Assertions.